# Rails 5 + Devise: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I created a new app with Rails 5 and Devise, set the authentication and everything was working well for a few weeks.

Today, I tried to log in on the production server and got this error:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

After some googling, I found out that I need to do this change:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #protect_from_forgery with: :exception # because of Devise + Rails 5 behavior
  protect_from_forgery prepend: true  

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    my_listings_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path
  end  
end
```

After this change and deploy on the production server, I try to log in - and error. But a different one - now the app redirects me on `my_listings_path` (which is all correct), but the problem is that I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `listings' for nil:NilClass
```

So I look what is the problem here, and:

```
@listings = current_user.listings.order('id DESC')
```

which means that `current_user` is empty (`nil`) -- how come? Also, I have in the `<head>` tag on the website this:

```
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Another note - on localhost, everything is working well, but on the production server I am keep getting those error messages.

Any advise?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your controller if you want `current_user` to work.
 I'm guessing that the reason it's working on localhost for you, is because you somehow have the current_user set in your session. I don't think it works if you try in incognito.

Comment: I've tried this - it looks like when I set `protect_from_forgery prepend: true`, then the app in production doesn't see that the user is logged in.

Comment: I think this may be because you're using `prepend: true`, try switching back to `protect_from_forgery with: exception` together with the `before_action :authenticate_user!` callback. I have a rails 5.1 app with those options and it's running properly in production.